# differences between writing haskell code directly in GHCi vs .hs file

Tags: haskell, ghci

I just began learning haskell a few days ago and I started with the first problem in "99 haskell questions" a few minutes ago.

The first one is fairly simple, to get the last element from a list. I was trying out various ways to solve, but I encountered the above error when I tried this little guy:

```
getLast = foldr1 $ flip const
```

I understand that this error occurs due to haskell being unable to infer the type of the function getLast and all I need to do is add an explicit type annotation for getLast.

But strangely, if I write the above code in GHCi, it works! How is this possible? Is somehow GHCi Clairvoyant and be able to deduce types now?

What are the major differences between writing a code directly in GHCi and writing haskell code in a .hs file and loading it?

Comment: You're running into the monomorphism restriction, if you put {-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-} at the top of your file it will work. See [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction)

Comment: GHCi runs with `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` by default, GHC does not. Another way to get rid of the error is to ditch the pointfree style. `getLast xs = foldr1 (flip const) xs` works too. You can reproduce the same general error by declaring e.g. `foo = show`, while `foo x = show x` is OK.

Comment: oops sorry, forgot to include the error : Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from a use of ‘foldr1’ 

And thanks for your answers n.m and pdexter :) 
But, how does ditching pointer free style make the code suddenly work? Is this also because of the monomorphism restriction ?

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan Yes. The MR does not apply to function bindings (i.e. non-pointfree), or to bindings with an explicit type annotations. The rationale is quite involved, leading to surprising results sometimes. Adding type annotations is good style, anyway, so in real-world code the MR is not such a big deal.

Comment: I understand the issue now, thanks everyone for the replies. 
Cheers

Comment: See especially the section on extended defaulting in the marked duplicate.